# bash and ash shell returns different error message for same command

Tags: linux, bash, ash

I'm using ash and bash shell in my embedded system, I got following error messages for same command using both shell

```
For ash shell
$ kill -9
sh: you need to specify whom to kill

For bash shell
$ kill -9
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

So,My question is why there are two different error messages for same command in two different shell? My understanding is error message return from command not from shell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is why there are two different error messages for same
>   command in two different shell?

Because `kill` is a shell-builtin (at least on `bash`).  This implies that is using `bash`, saying `kill ...` would execute the shell builtin and not the binary that might reside in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`.

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ type kill
kill is a shell builtin
$ kill
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
$ which kill
/bin/kill
$ /bin/kill
usage: kill [-s signal_name] pid ...
       kill -l [exit_status]
       kill -signal_name pid ...
       kill -signal_number pid ...
```

You could disable the shell-builtins in `bash` by making use of the `enable` builtin:

```
$ enable -n kill
$ kill
usage: kill [-s signal_name] pid ...
       kill -l [exit_status]
       kill -signal_name pid ...
       kill -signal_number pid ...
```

(Invoking `kill` after disabling the builtin invokes the system `/bin/kill` instead.)

Comment: very nice answer devnull.